# Where can i see when maintenance will be over?

Tags: diablo-iii, battle.net

Diablo 3 runs on battle.net and the Battle.net servers are down for Maintenance (Error 33), most maintenance are planed for a set time period where can I go to see when they will be up again?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

http://us.battle.net/d3/en/status will show you the current status of the servers, while you'll want to check the forums for more specific details on how long downtimes are expected to last - http://us.battle.net/d3/en/forum/5394512/ for the US Service Status forums, http://eu.battle.net/d3/en/forum/4436696/ for the EU Technical Support forums (usually outages/maintenances seem to be stickied there, as there appears to be no Service Status forum for the region currently).